# How to find the crash details using address value from .so file

Tags: c++, debugging, binary, .so

I have a binary abc.so which get crash, and its in stripped format so not able to get the other symbols details other than the address.

I wanted to debug the following address.

```
(gdb) bt #0 0xb438f92a in ?? () from /usr/lib/abc.so #1 0xb2aaac38 in ?? () from /usr/lib/abc.so
```

I tried using addr2line to find the file, linenumber and other info by running the following command:

```
addr2line -i -f -e libvega_webview.so 0xb438f92a
```

The above did not worked, so I realised may the the address which I am passing might not be the one. So I tried find the offset:

```
objdump -f adb.so output: adb.so: file format ittle start address 0x055f1300
offset: 0xb2aaac38 - 0x055f1300 ==> 0xad4b9938
```

and then:

```
addr2line -i -f -e libvega_webview.so 0xad4b9938
```

but still no luck, not sure what I am missing.
Can anyone please help me on this, not sure if I'm still calculating the correct offset.

Comment: Please edit question and detail what is the output of the last command.